# copy one picture and paste it on top of the other on terminal

Tags: terminal, applescript, automator

In here I found a piece of [code](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1777781) that finds and resizes all images within a folder with applescript

Now I need to apply a stamp to those images one by one. I already have a transparent jpg prepared with the same size and ready to be pasted on all of them.

I just lack the knowledge to do it on terminal so I could mix it with applescript.

Does anyone know how to do this without making a workflow? Because it takes a lot of time and keeps the laptop busy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Again :-)**

You can get the height of an image like this:

```
identify -format "%h" image.jpg
500
```

and the width like this:

```
identify -format "%w" image.jpg
800
```

If you want to find the lesser of the height and the width, and then take 10% of that for your logo size and make it integer, you would do:

```
identify -format "%[fx:int(0.1*min(h,w))]" image.jpg
50
```

If you want to put that in a variable, you would do

```
logosize=$(identify -format "%[fx:int(0.1*min(h,w))]" image.jpg)

echo $logosize
50
```

You could then use that in the original command below like this:

```
convert image.jpg -gravity southeast                           \
      \( copyright.png -resize "${logosize}x${logosize} \)     \
      -composite result.jpg
```

I suspect you are going to want to run that with the `find` command, aren't you? :-)

```
find . -iname \*.jpg -exec bash -c 'echo Processing {};logosize=$(identify -format "%[fx:int(0.1*min(h,w))]" "{}"); echo $logosize;convert "{}" -gravity southeast \( copyright.png -resize "$logosizex$logosize" \) -composite "{}"' \;
```

**Updated Answer**

If you want to resize your original image before compositing the logo unchanged on top, use a command like this:

```
convert image.jpg -resize 2000x1000 -gravity southeast copyright.png -composite result.jpg
```

If you want to resize the logo before compositing it on top of the unchanged original image, use a command like this:

```
convert image.jpg -gravity southeast \( copyright.png -resize 700x200! \) -composite result.jpg
```

**Original Answer**

I would use ImageMagick. It is extremely powerful and simple to install if you use `homebrew`. Ask if you don't know how...

Let's assume you have an image called `image.jpg` and a transparent logo/copyright called `copyright.png`.

**image.jpg**

[image]

**copyright.png**

[image]

Then the command to do a single image would be:

```
convert image.jpg copyright.png -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

If your logo/copyright and image are different sizes, and you want to force the logo to, say, the bottom right corner, just set the `-gravity` accordingly like this:

```
convert image.jpg -gravity southeast copyright.png -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

If you wanted to do all the JPEGs in the folder, you would need a loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s nocaseglob

for f in *.jpg; do
   convert "$f" copyright.png -composite "$f"
done
```

By the way, you cannot have a transparent JPEG - that format doesn't support transparency.

If you are really intent on using Applescript - I don't know why anyone would be - you can call the above using `do shell script` - make the file executable first. Ask if unsure how.

If you want to recurse down into all directories (folders) starting at the one you are currently located in and add the logo/copyright to all images, I would **make a copy of them somewhere else first** and do a trial run. The command would be:

```
find . -iname "*.jpg" -exec convert "{}" copyright.png -composite "{}" \;
```

That says... *"find, starting at the current directory (.), disregarding upper/lower case (-iname), all files ending in "JPG", and apply the logo/copyright to them, resaving on top of the original file"*.

Comment: You're right, it's a png, sorry. The applescript was to avoid having to make the bash since I had done it already for resizing. 

In all of my searches i did find something about ImageMagick! But never explaining this. Thank you so much! you have been very helpful. Going to try it.

Comment: You can add the resizing into the command above if you want to, like this: `convert image.jpg -resize 1024x768 copyright.png -composite result.jpg`

Comment: I'm using the bash since it's done already. The folder has many others inside. I should use find then instead of copyright.png right?

Comment: it worked beautifully. Ever go to Portugal let me buy you a beer. no. a six pack

Comment: My pleasure - glad to be of assistance. Good luck!

Comment: Is there a way to resize the stamp before pasting? because it's size will remain the same but the images sizes change (I decided it's even better to just use the pictures in their actual size since this is possible in a one liner)

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. Very good answer and that too might prove very helpful but, (and if you don't mind else I'll just go look it up) is it possible to do the resize of the logo to a percentage of the picture's area?

Comment: I have added that - plus a horrendous command to run it recursively!

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue years ago, and the only way I found is an Applescript using Photoshop (duplicate layer containing the logo on the photo and flatten file).
the script loops to all file of a folder.

... but you need Photoshop for this script !
I can share that script if it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't have photoshop and I think it'd be very powerful to do it with the command line so I'll stick around and see if someone else has any ideas